# Taxonomy menu - translation of terms

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I have website with 2 languages and 2 different categories. I would like to use taxonomy menu on both languages, but I want just to translate these terms to my language and use taxonomy as menu.

When editing taxonomy I have 3 options to pick:

**Localize.**

*Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized.*

It seems that this is solution I'm looking for: I want to have translated terms ad just add nodes and pick category. But this is not working.

**Translate.**

*Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated.*

This does not work too.

**Fixed Language.**

*Terms will have a global language and they will only show up for pages in that language.*

I don't want to have 2 different terms, I want to have one term translated, so this solution is not for me.

When I say that it's not working I mean, that on when other language is selected, whole page is translated into this language, but not taxonomy menu. I remember that I wrote my own block for displaying it, but then I had to add translated path to each term.

Is there a possibility in drupal to have:

1. Menu based on taxonomy (for example: taxonomy has terms: Bikes and Cars)?
2. Translated terms and displayed in menu depend on current site language (for en: Bikes/Cars, for french: Vélo/Auto)?
3. Translated paths for taxonomy terms (Bikes => bikes, Cars => cars, Vélo => velo, Auto => auto)?

How to manage this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, localize term is the choice you shoud use but remember to refresh your translation interface on admin/build/translate/refresh after changing taxonomy translation setting.
For menu based on taxonomy, you could use [TaxonomyMenu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) and for localized menu address, i18nmenu  is a good choice.

Comment: Have you seen the part where Bobby says `But this is not working.`?

Answer (score 1):

It will work only in 7.x-2.x version with re-introduction of the `Add item for Vocabulary` option.

https://drupal.org/node/1034310

But check this one also:

https://drupal.org/node/1665308

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question, but for people with the same problem as in question (2):

**Taxonomies linked to a content type won't show the translation by default** (even if you have translated the taxonomy) To show the localized version, you have to change the display options.

Go to structure > content types > (content type)
Click on 'manage display'. There, you have the option to change the format, eg. link -> link (localized)